# How to create newline delimited json-lines file from list of python dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to create a JSON-lines file of data so that is compatible with google cloud AI platform's [requirements for online prediction](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/online-predict).

Right now I have a list of dictionaries for each of my data points. It looks like this:

```
data = [{'values': [0,1,0], 'key': 0}, {'values': [1,1,0], 'key': 1}]
```

I'm exporting this data to **data.json** with the following code:

```
import json
json_filepath = "data.json"
with open(json_filepath, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

The problem is, this **data.json** file then looks exactly like my data (viz. a list of dictionaries). How can I make this **data.json** file a new-line delimited collection of each dictionary in the list? In other words, how can I make it look like this:

```
{'values': [0,1,0], 'key': 0}
{'values': [1,1,0], 'key': 1}
```

Comment: That is not json.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the post to remove any reference to the file as being JSON format. Instead, I'm referring to it as 'JSON Lines' format, per Andrew's comment below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can loop through the array and dump each object followed by a new line `'\n'`:

```
with open(json_filepath, 'w') as f:
    for d in data:
        json.dump(d, f)
        f.write('\n')
```

Alternatively, you can use a one-liner using `json.dumps`, `str.join`, and `map`:

```
with open(json_filepath, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(map(json.dumps, data)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
with open(json_filepath, "w") as f:
    for datum in data:
        f.write(json.dumps(datum))
        f.write("\n")
```

I should also mention in general this is known as the "JSON Lines" data format.